# Are there any ATMs in Victoria Falls, Zimbabwe that dispense USD?

Tags: money, zimbabwe, victoria-falls

I know there ATMs in Harare and Bulawayo that dispense USD.  What about Victoria Falls? I didn't see any in Victoria Falls last time I was there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most [other forums online](http://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/thread.jspa?threadID=2115731) indicate that now the Zimbabwean ATMs in Vic Falls dispense USD.

[VictoriaFalls-Guide.net](http://www.victoriafalls-guide.net/victoria-falls-questions.html) indicates that:

> Barclays Bank and several of the other banks now have ATM cash
>   withdrawal facilities accepting Visa and Master Cards and **dispensing
>   US$ cash**. The limit is the same as your limit back home. Charges are
>   $1.25 per transaction plus the charge from your local bank which can
>   be 2 to 3 %.

Comment: Actually now you say Barclays in Victoria Falls I remember where it was now. Right next to the post office next to the old railway station on the way to the bridge.

Answer (score 2):

There is also an ATM I can't remember the brand in the shopping area near chicken-inn off the main road.

The Barclays ATM was giving out large notes (100USD) which can be hard to get rid of in the local shops. Its probably best to have a bunch of 1, 5, 10 USD notes with you when you arrive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are there and as mentioned Barclays Bank is the best bet and accepts various international cards.